# python discord bot create_channel commmand adding an arg to command to make bot add a specific member of the server to the perms of the channel

Tags: python, discord.py

```
elif cmd_args[0].upper() == "D!CREATECHANNEL":
         everyone = discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False, send_messages=False, create_instant_invite=False, manage_channel=False, manage_permissions=False, manage_webhooks=False, send_TTS_messages=False, manage_messages=False, embed_links=False, attach_files=False, read_message_history=False, mention_everyone=False, use_external_emojis=False, add_reactions=False)
         Member = discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True, create_instant_invite=False, manage_channel=False, manage_permissions=False, manage_webhooks=False)
         server = message.server
         await client.create_channel(server, cmd_args[1], (server.default_role, everyone), (discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name='Member'), Member))
         pass
```

the bot makes a channel like this https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/471468848718020623/473202969492455425/gng.PNG (the command rn that makes this is D!createchannel name)
what i want the bot to do is do this https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/471468848718020623/473202968989138945/Capturegbgg.PNG (for it to do this i want the command to be D!createchannel name @The Golden Atlas [16-A]) I just don't know how to make it do it mabey I am being dumb and don't see it but I really need this help its the last bit of my bot that needs work

Answer (score 0):

You can get all of the mentioned members from `message.member`, then build a `(target, PermissionOverwrite)` tuple for each of them and pass that to `create_channel`.

```
elif cmd_args[0].upper() == "D!CREATECHANNEL":
    everyone = discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False, send_messages=False, create_instant_invite=False, manage_channel=False, manage_permissions=False, manage_webhooks=False, send_TTS_messages=False, manage_messages=False, embed_links=False, attach_files=False, read_message_history=False, mention_everyone=False, use_external_emojis=False, add_reactions=False)
    Member = discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True, create_instant_invite=False, manage_channel=False, manage_permissions=False, manage_webhooks=False)
    server = message.server
    member_perms = [(mentioned, Member) for mentioned in message.mentions]        
    await client.create_channel(server, cmd_args[1], (server.default_role, everyone), (discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name='Member'), Member), *member_perms)
```

Comment: okay that works partially what I want only I want the specific person perms to be different that the role Member sorry if the name of that role got you confused

Comment: It's pretty trivial to create a third `PermissionOverwrite` object and use that to make `member_perms` instead.